# Corruption of the heap using OpenCV C++ HOG Detector

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, heap-corruption

Hi stackoverflow community,

I've been developing an algorithm using OpenCV library. I didn't have any memory issues until now when I'm integrating the algorithm in an application. I'm not very skilled in C++ and "properly coding" so I don't know what can cause the problem.

The error I get when I release the code is the typical "corruption of the heap". In the code below you can see the function in which I get the breakpoint.

I think the problem is related to my *Mat frametemp*. What I do in this function is send a Mat as parameter, then I copy that Mat to a temporary Mat and work with that one (detecting persons in the image and marking a rectangle in them). Finally I return that temporary Mat. There has to be something wrong with memory allocation/deallocation of these Mat but I can't find an answer for this. Anything that is wrong in my code sure can help me to solve the breakpoint. Thanks in advance for answering.

```
Mat predetection(Mat &frame){

    Mat rois;
    Mat frametemp;
    frame.copyTo(frametemp);

    // HOG for people detections
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    static vector<float> detector = HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector();
    if (!detector.size()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: getDefaultPeopleDetector returned NULL\n");     
    }
    hog.setSVMDetector(detector);

    fflush(stdout);
    vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
    vector<double> foundWeights, foundWeights_filtered;

    // run the detector with default parameters. to get a higher hit-rate
    // (and more false alarms, respectively), decrease the hitThreshold and
    // groupThreshold (set groupThreshold to 0 to turn off the grouping completely).
    hog.detectMultiScale(frametemp, found, foundWeights, 0, Size(8, 8), Size(32, 32), 1.05, 2);


    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < found.size(); i++)
    {

        Rect r1 = found[i];
        double prescore = foundWeights[i];
        for (j = 0; j < found.size(); j++)
            if (j != i && (r1 & found[j]) == r1)
                break;
        if (j == found.size()){
            found_filtered.push_back(r1);
            foundWeights_filtered.push_back(prescore);
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r2 = found_filtered[i];
        double prescore_filtered = foundWeights_filtered[i];
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        x1 = r2.x;
        y1 = r2.y;
        x2 = r2.x + r2.width;
        y2 = r2.y + r2.height;

        // the HOG detector returns slightly larger rectangles than the real objects.
        // so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
        r2.x += cvRound(r2.width*0.1);
        r2.width = cvRound(r2.width*0.8);
        r2.y += cvRound(r2.height*0.07);
        r2.height = cvRound(r2.height*0.8);
        rectangle(frametemp, r2.tl(), r2.br(), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }
    return frametemp;
}
```

And this is the call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlpBreakPointHeap@4()  + 0x19 bytes 
ntdll.dll!RtlpValidateHeapEntry()  + 0x3088c bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlDebugFreeHeap@12()  + 0xbf bytes  
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeap()  + 0x44b2f bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap()  + 0x1ba bytes  
msvcr100.dll!free(void * pBlock)  Line 51   C
DiVA_detector3.exe!predetection(cv::Mat & frame)  Line 70 + 0x9e bytes  C++
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Mat` class have an appropriate and correct copy constructor? It gets called when you do `return frametemp`, and if it's got a bug you can get these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Mat class is a predefined class in OpenCV libraries so I guess it has an appropriate copy constructor (which I don't really know what it is...). I took a look at Mat class information and I found this statement: "Use a copy constructor or assignment operator where there can be an array or expression on the right side (see below). As noted in the introduction, the array assignment is an O(1) operation because it only copies the header and increases the reference counter. The Mat::clone() method can be used to get a full (deep) copy of the array when you need it."

Comment: I will try to make clone() instead of frame.copyTo() method and maybe this is the mistake... I will check it and post the result.